# preg_match > sign

Tags: php, regex

I am not so into this PCRE patterns. Anyway I need help. How to replace

```
sometext >
```

with an empty string (`""`).

this is php code

```
preg_replace("/Sometext >/", "", $subject);
```

Comment: if this is to be used for parsing HTML, I'll direct you [here](http://htmlparsing.com/php.html) instead.

Comment: no i need to replace "sometext >" with ""

Comment: In two of the answers below, you say "not working".  What does "not working" mean? What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are case sensitive by default. Add the [`i` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to change this behavior:

```
echo preg_replace("/Sometext >/i", "", "hello sometext > world"); // hello  world
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind *not* using regex for this:

```
$text = 'somethingElse sometext >';
$text = str_replace('sometext >','',$text);
```

Comment: I did just make an edit. Check if you have the same code.

Comment: @pregmatch, *not working* helps no one. Use your words and provide the necessary details to receive help.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much information, but based on it, I would go with this

```
<?php
$subjects[] = "Sometext > hello!";
$subjects[] = "sometext > yup";
$subjects[] = "SOMETEXT > OMG";
$subjects[] = "SomeText > talking?";

foreach($subjects as $subject){
    echo preg_replace ("/sometext >/i","",$subject)."<br />";
}
```

outputs this:

```
hello! 
yup 
OMG 
talking?
```

Comment: this replace everything. I need to replace sometext > with ""

Comment: is `sometext` an example or the exact text you want to replace?

Comment: this is example sometext > replace with ""

Comment: so, you don't want to replace the `>`?

Comment: no no, i want to replace "sometext >" with ""

Answer (score 0):

I know that this simple

```
echo preg_replace("/Sometext >/i", "", "hello sometext > world");
```

!
should be working. But it does not. This "sometext >" is dynamically generated stuff. Anyway I am deleting question ...